# Is $b_n={-1 \over 1\times2}+{-1 \over 2\times3}+ \dots + {(-1)^{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor} \over n(n+1)}$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let
$$b_n={-1 \over 1\times2}+{-1 \over 2\times3}+ \dots + {(-1)^{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor} \over n(n+1)}$$
Is this series convergent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Even better the series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: You have $\vert{(-1)^{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor} \over n(n+1)} \vert \le \frac{1}{n^2} $ and $\frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent

Comment: thanks. As soon as I posted the comment I realized it. That was why I erased it.

Answer (score 0):

I will expand on mathcounterexamples.net's answer:

It is absolutely convergent because of the comparison test. If I call $a_n$ to the $n $th term of your series,

$$|a_n| \lt \frac1{n^2} $$

Which is known to converge